# How to retrieve pause and if playing in fullscreen with HTML5 Video on Android 4.0?

Tags: android, html, video, html5-video

Hey I have a few questions about HTML5 VIDEO for Android 4.0 default browser.

I want to play the video always on fullscreen, i was successful on doing that by the following code

```
onClick = playVideo();
function playVideo() {
    player.load();
    player.webkitEnterFullScreen();
    player.play(); 
}
```

So I need to know a couple of things though that would help me so much...,

1. is there a way to tell if the video is playing fullscreen. I was able to get that for iphone by checking webkitDisplayingFullScreen, so this is fired off on done button by iphone.
   Android has only back button, is there a response button for that as well?
2. pause does not fire an event when playing in default videoplayer, is there a way to implement an event that the default player is paused?
3. the play() function does not work on Android 4.0 default player, any reason why this is or am i not calling it right? It works on Chrome Browser

Thanx, any help would be great.